# Library of alternativeFunction() in R

Tags: r, r-library

I am trying to read 2 different types of files, using the alternativeFunction(). So if the first file in .txt format could not be found, I could try with the second type in .csv format, but R tells me that the function is not found. Does anyone know the library I have to install?

> ```
> File <- try(read.table('File.txt',sep=c(',','|'), header=TRUE))
> ```

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'File.txt': No such file or directory

> ```
> if("try-error" %in% class(File)) alternativeFunction(File <- read_csv('File.csv'))
> ```

Error in alternativeFunction(File <- read_csv("File.csv")) :
could not find function "alternativeFunction"

Comment: You can have only a single `sep`

Comment: Where is `alternativeFunction()` from? That's not a base R function. It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.